# Screenshot fullscreen game using DirectX 10/11

Tags: c++, directx

I searched all day for answers on this topic and this is what I found:

1. WinAPI screenshot - No
2. You can take screenshots using outdated directx 9
3. You can take screenshots using Hook with new DirectX

What I already tried:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "screenshoter.h"
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <wincodec.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

HWND targetHWND = nullptr;

BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowsProc(__in HWND hWnd, __in LPARAM lParam) {
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
    if (length == 0)
        return true;
    auto buffer = new TCHAR[512];
    memset( buffer, 0, ( 512 ) * sizeof( TCHAR ) );
    GetWindowText( hWnd, buffer, 512 );
    auto windowTitle = std::string(buffer);
    DWORD proc = NULL;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &proc);
    GetModuleFileNameEx(OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, false, proc), nullptr, buffer, 512);
    auto filePath = std::string(buffer);
    auto pos = filePath.find_last_of('\\');
    auto fileName = filePath.substr(pos + 1);
    delete[] buffer;
    if (windowTitle == "Overwatch" && fileName == "Overwatch.exe")
        targetHWND = hWnd;
        //std::cout << Title: " << windowTitle << " |  Filename: " << fileName << std::endl;
    return true;
}

int screenshoter::take() {
    std::cout << EnumWindows(enumWindowsProc, NULL) << std::endl;
    IDirect3DSurface9* pRenderTarget=NULL;
    IDirect3DSurface9* pDestTarget=NULL;
    IDirect3D9 *pD3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    IDirect3DDevice9* Device=NULL;
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp = { 0 };
    D3DDISPLAYMODE DisplayMode;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = targetHWND;
    d3dpp.Windowed = ((GetWindowLong(targetHWND, GWL_STYLE) & WS_POPUP) != 0) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    if (FAILED(pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, d3dpp.hDeviceWindow, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &Device)))
    {
        pD3D->Release();
        return false;
    }
    const char file[] = "Pickture.bmp";
    // sanity checks.
    if (Device == NULL)
        return 0;

    // get the render target surface.
    HRESULT hr = Device->GetRenderTarget(0, &pRenderTarget);
    // get the current adapter display mode.
    hr = pD3D->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,&DisplayMode);

    // create a destination surface.
    hr = Device->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(DisplayMode.Width,
                                             DisplayMode.Height,
                                             DisplayMode.Format,
                                             D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM,
                                             &pDestTarget,
                                             NULL);
    //copy the render target to the destination surface.
    hr = Device->GetRenderTargetData(pRenderTarget, pDestTarget);
    //save its contents to a bitmap file.

    hr = D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile(file,
                               D3DXIFF_JPG,
                               pDestTarget,
                               NULL,
                               NULL);

    // clean up.
    pRenderTarget->Release();
    pDestTarget->Release();
    return 0;
}
```

My program searches for game process/window

But the problem is there is no d3dx9.h on my system

So I can't use D3DXIFF_JPG

Comment: Where I would start is to download the source of OBS (used to record games etc) and have a look at how they do it.

Comment: So the problem is, that you need help on how to install the d3dx9.h header? That should probably be your first sentence / title of the question.

Comment: @nada no, I can install DirectX SDK from 2010. I want to use something new

Comment: If you want still images, verify the printscreen key works then synthesize it programmatically with SendInput.

If you want video, desktop duplication API, hard to use and delivers data in VRAM but is quite fast. To save a D3D 11 texture, use https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Inc/ScreenGrab.h it can even encode jpeg/png with a WIC version. Encoding video is very hard however, you need a GPU hardware encoder, but integrating DD with media foundation is quite hard. Another option is look for vendor specific tech, both NVidia and AMD have some APIs to capture games.

Comment: @Soonts Thank u much, I will try nvidia capture sdk